# Excel - Conditionnal formatting with formula not working but the formula itself works

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to format a column of file paths depending on their extension (e.g. *.css*).

The said column of file paths looks like the following (3rd column)
[image: column of file paths]

In another sheet, I have the following table named `FileExtensionsTbl` in which every column contains the extension for a conditional format. For example, all the extensions in column CSS would be used to match a specific style like all files ending with `.css` would match the CSS conditional format.
[image: File extensions table]

I came up with a formula that works when used in the same sheet where the file paths are.

Here is the formula: 
`=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(LOWER(RIGHT(RC3; LEN(RC3)-FIND(".";RC3)+1)); FileExtensionsTbl[CSS]; 0)))`

Here is the result (4th column):
[image: Formula result]

The problem is that I can't figure out a way to make it work as a formula for conditional formatting.

Here is the error I get when I try to use it in conditional formatting:
[image: Conditionnal format error]

***Note:*** I'm using the R1C1 reference notation (relative)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't use structured references in conditional formatting formulas. Two suggestions:

1) Replace `FileExtensionsTbl[CSS]` by its column reference. Assumed CSS types are on the sheet *File Extensions* in column *A* your formula would be:

```
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(LOWER(RIGHT(RC3; LEN(RC3)-FIND(".";RC3)+1)); 'File Extensions'!A:A; 0)))
```

2) Or use [this trick](https://wmfexcel.com/2019/01/19/the-indirect-trick-of-using-structured-reference-in-conditional-formatting/) and enclose the structured reference with `INDIRECT`:

```
=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(LOWER(RIGHT(RC3; LEN(RC3)-FIND(".";RC3)+1)); INDIRECT("FileExtensionsTbl[CSS]"); 0)))
```