# How to use COUNTIF for conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting, countif

I am trying to use a formula to highlight cells which exist in another range with conditional formatting. The formula I am using is:

```
=COUNTIF(VerticalList,A1)=0
```

When pressing OK, Excel tells me that there is a problem with the formula. I don't see the problem. Can someone help me out? What is wrong with my formula?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can't repro. Can you add a screenshot maybe?

Comment: do you use `;` instead of `,` in your formula?  does the formula work outside of Conditional Formating?  Are you spelling the named range correctly?

Comment: I've attached a screenshot in the main question if that helps? @BigBen

Comment: Is the named range worksheet or workbook scope? if worksheet scope include the name of the worksheet on which the range is found.

Comment: Does help. I'd echo @ScottCraner's comments.

Comment: Formula does work outside of conditional formatting. I don't have either a ; or , in my formula? The named range is on another sheet in the same workbook.

Comment: I am at the end of my guessing, try to do the formula with the actual range and not a named range and see if that works.  As stated we cannot reproduce the problem on our end.

Comment: Okey doke - thank you :-)

Comment: Is it possible that this is an Excel for Mac related problem? I have experienced trouble when using named ranges in VBA on Mac. I cannot test it on Mac now, but the formula works fine on my Windows 10 PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other day another SO user had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59073868). I think you cannot use a structed reference in a conditional formatting formula.

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("VerticalList"),A1)=0
```

Comment: Awesome! We have a winner! Thank you :-)